# riverpod doesn't set stateful provider's internal state to AsyncData(null)

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm using riverpod 2.3.6, and I can't get riverpod to update the internal state of a stateful provider from a value, to null. The value is wrapped in AsyncValue, and is supposed to be updated when the value is different than the current state.

```dart
@riverpod
class Somethings extends _$Somethings {
  @override
  Future<Something?> build() async { ... }

  Future<void> _doSomething() async {
    final something = await _getSomething();

    if (!GeneratedObjectEquality.somethingsAreEqual(state.value, something)) {
      // update the state
->    final newState = AsyncData(something);
->    state = newState;
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

This is currently working fine when the state goes from `AsyncData(null)` to `AsyncData(something)`, but when it goes from `AsyncData(something)` to `AsyncData(null)`, the state isn't actually updated.

#### How can I set the state to null?

Is this an unsupported way of setting the state to null? Do I need to use some sort of wrapper class instead of `Something?`, like a Java `Optional<Something>`?

Comment: The default test for "emits a state" is object identity (identical()).  However, null should not be the same as the previous state, so it should emit.  Can you reduce this down to an example we can run?

Comment: Also, just noticed you're doing your own test for "same".  You can either leave that out, or if the identical() logic isn't proper, override the updateShouldNotify method of your notifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a minimum reproducible example, but for some reason, it's not behaving the same way. As far as I can tell, my main project, and the mre are built the same (they're both generating the same kind of provider). Since I can't reproduce the issue simply, I'm closing my question.

For anyone with a similar issue, I was able to make it work by changing my provider like this:

```
@riverpod
class Somethings extends _$Somethings {
> Something? _something;

  @override
  Future<Something?> build() async {
    ...
->  return _something;
  }

  Future<void> _doSomething() async {
    final something = await _getSomething();

->  if (!GeneratedObjectEquality.somethingsAreEqual(_something, something)) {
      // update the state
->    _something = something;
->    state = AsyncData(_something);
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for changing state of provider class you can use  update() method . which give you a function with access to state value and you can change the value with help of that :

update((data)=>);

i hope this answer help you with what you want .